# Image in django admin InlineModel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, backend

I have these models and i want to add **SampleImage** model in to **Orderdetail** as InlineModel.And want to display images in **orderdetail** model.I tried lot of answer already posted in stackoverflow but i can't configure my answer.

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, )


class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name_in_logo = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    describe_website_and_audience = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.OneToOneField(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    industry = models.OneToOneField(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)


class SampleImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/tile_images')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    industry = models.ManyToManyField(Industry)
    orderdetail = models.ForeignKey(OrderDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

Comment: What part of this is not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: i have this code in SampleImage       `def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="{}" width="150" height="150"/>'.format(self.image))

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'`                                                               and **admin.py**   have                                                                                           `class SampleImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = SampleImages
    filter_vertical = ('category',)
    readonly_fields = ['image_tag']
admin.site.register(SampleImages, SampleImageAdmin)`   but my image is not showing.

Comment: Can you inspect your html and see if it is at least rendering an `<img>` tag?

Comment: yes i inspect and its showing <img> tag with correct src value.

Comment: If the img tag is correct, than this sounds more like a css or maybe html nesting issue. Could you post the relevant css and html?

Comment: @Snackoverflow thanks for help. my problem get solved with another method.